# External JS file not loading after submit

Tags: javascript, php

I have a js file in domain1 that is working fine in domain1. But if I connect the js (from domain1) to domain2, it is not working.

The js file is a connection to a PHP file in domain1 to output some results. How can i make it work in domain2?

[I want to make the js work from the domain1 itself]

Here the js file in domain1,

```
function sendQuery() {
    var container = $('#DisplayDiv');
    $(container).html('<img src="http://www.domain1.com/loading.gif">');
    var newhtml = '';

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'http://www.www.domain1.com/data.php',
        data: $('#SubmitForm').serialize(),
        success: function (response) {
            $('#DisplayDiv').html(response);
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

It is working till loading.gif file, but no data is output from the external output.php file from domain2.

[Here domain1 & domain2 are used only as examples]

**WORKING FINE NOW!!**

Thanks to @Ohgodwhy, Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*" in .htaccess in domain1.

Comment: how do you use js in domain2 , show ur code.

Comment: check in chrome console, and write what error you are getting. And how you have included js in domain 2 ?

Comment: the script is same in both domain1 and domain2. But only the difference is that in domain2, i am changing the js file to load it from domain1.

Comment: __how do you load it in domain2__?

Comment: In domain1 it is working fine. But in domain2 it is not able to load the external php file from js.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.domain1.com/query.js"></script> to call the js file from domain1 in domain2

Comment: This is because of `cross origin resource sharing`. You need to either enable `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://domain2.com` or, you need to use `JSONP`. Alternatively, send it to a script on `domain2.com`, and use `php` to fetch the script and return it to the ajax function.

Comment: Thanks Ohgodwhy, it is working now. Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*" in .htaccess of domain1. Working fine now

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what you want Exactly .. If you past Your code Here it will be Excellent ..
But i think if you want to Connect any 'js' file from any domain to your domain you can use the ordinary deceleration for it :

in HTML:

```
<script type = "text/javascript" src="https://googledrive.com/host/0B248VFEZkAAiNjhxaDNUZVpsVHM" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

in PHP :

```
echo '<script type = "text/javascript" src="https://googledrive.com/host/0B248VFEZkAAiNjhxaDNUZVpsVHM" charset="utf-8"></script>';
```

Very important note :
1- You must take care of Script order for dependent script.
2- The element which you call must be attend and visible during cal time.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript don't allow cross domain AJAX call.
There ae some options available to do that like **JSONP**

See this link for more options : [link](http://jquery-howto.blogspot.in/2013/09/jquery-cross-domain-ajax-request.html)